# Any suggestions on Infopath form library and form template deployment in SharePoint2010

Tags: infopath

I need to deploy a Infopath form library with custom form template to SharePoint2010 ,once we save the form to the form library it will kick off a custom workflow(very similar to the built-in approval workflow).I woulk like to know any recommendations or gotha for deployment and subsequent uprade for form template or form library in the future.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you might want to consider for future form upgrades is using Content Types for you form revisions.  When you publish a revised form template, your existing forms will top working if fields are removed from it, for example.  However, publishing your templates as new content types will allow the older templates to live on when people open an older form.